# i have below text for that need to write regular expression

Tags: python

```
s1='Applying update\u2026 (Step 5 of 6) '
s2='Applying update\u2026 (Step 4 of 6) '
s3='Applying update\u2026 (Step 4 of 6) '
```

1.I think pattern should be like Applying update.*(Step\s5\sof\s6).*'
2.this may throw error can you help me to do this

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood correctly what you need to do but, would this help?

```
def printStepUpdate(iCurrentStep, iNSteps):
    assert (type(iCurrentStep) is int)
    assert (type(iNSteps) is int)
    strMessage = ('Applying update\u2026 (Step {} of {})').format(iCurrentStep, iNSteps)
    print(strMessage)
```

You could then call it using:

```
printStepUpdate(5, 6)
```

And the output would look like this:

```
Applying update… (Step 5 of 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use services as [regextester](https://www.regextester.com/) to test your regular expressions

This regex should work with your text

```
your_regex = re.compile(r'Applying update.+ \(Step [0-9] of [0-9]\)')
```